# To ignore linenumber's selection in Less inside Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to develop a selection-tool for Screen which ignores the leading spaces and numbers in selection.

**Problems**

1. **What is the code which affects selection-tool `C-a Esc` in Screen?**
2. To make an algorithm which ignores the linenumbers and the space at the beginning from the selection:

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/%20selection-less.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/%20selection-less.png)

The following Perl-regex seems to match the beginning of the line

```
 {5}[1-9]{1-4} {8}         # not tested
```

The selection tool apparently works by concatenating an increase in selection to the current selection. For instance, one line is selected. I select another one: a new line is added to the selection queue. The reverse is true also for a decrease in selection.

I want to put the Perl regex on when the selection obverses `\n` such that the ignorance of the line is considered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to select columns.  That'd be much easier than a regex.

From the [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) manpage:

> ```
>    c or C to set the left or right margin respectively. If no
>      repeat  count is  given,   both default  to the  current
>      cursor position.
>      Example: Try this on a  rather full text screen:  "C-a [
>      M 20 l SPACE c 10 l 5 j C SPACE".
>
>      This moves one  to the middle line of  the screen, moves
>      in  20 columns left,  marks the  beginning of  the paste
>      buffer, sets the left column, moves 5 columns down, sets
>      the right  column, and then  marks the end of  the paste
>      buffer. Now try:
>      "C-a [ M 20 l SPACE 10 l 5 j SPACE"
>
>      and notice the difference in the amount of text copied.
> ```

So, in your screenshot, press `C-a [`, move the cursor to the beginning of your text, press `SPACE` and then press `c`.  Move to the end of your selection and then press `SPACE` again.  Now you have the text you want.

Hope this wasn't too much info. You tagged it with beginner so I wasn't sure if you were a perl or screen beginner.

Comment: @seth: Thank you for your answer! --- Your answer is really a shortcut. --- I am interested in which code affects the button under `c`. Do you know where is the code for the function under `c`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I've just always used the 'c' key to select columns.  Never dug too deep into it.