# Where is the code for the function under c in Screen's copy-mode?

Tags: macos, gnu-screen

This question is based on the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100556/to-ignore-linenumbers-selection-in-less-inside-screen/1100596#1100596).

I am interested in the function under the button `c` because of my current interest in the similar function in the column detection of OS X S.Leopard's Preview.

Where is the code for the function under c in Screen's copy-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/screen-4.0.3.tar.gz), in `mark.c`, starting on line 733.